# Basic results concerning the intertwining operator in the $\mathrm{SL}_2$ case

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions, langlands-conjectures, analytic-continuation

I am reading [Ikeda, Tamotsu, On the location of poles of the triple L-functions]. On page 194, the author recalled some known results concerning $\operatorname{SL}_2$. I would like to know any reference about this. Or any reference that is beneficial to understand these facts would help a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

These results turned out to be immediate consequences of the calculations in Section 4.5 of Bump's book, Automorphic forms and representations. One should be careful there is a mistake in the book about the gamma-factor.

Comment: What is the mistake?  Also, don't forget to accept your own answer if it addresses the question!